# Rails - will_paginate gem not working when using .each do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

EDIT: I've altered the code to now read:

View code:

```
<h3>Your Orders:</h3>
<table class="order-items">
<th>Date</th>
<th>Order No.</th>
<th>View Order</th>
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= order.created_at.strftime("%d %b. %Y") %></td>
        <td><%= order.id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show',  order_path(order) %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>   
</table>

<p><%= will_paginate @orders %></p>
```

Controller Code:

```
@customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
@orders = @customer.orders.paginate page: params[:page], order: 'id desc',
  per_page: 5
```

Routes:

```
resources :orders

resources :customers

get 'admin' => 'admin#index'

get 'account' => 'customers#show'

match '/account', :to => 'customers#show'

match'/signup', :to => 'customers#new'

controller :sessions do
  get  'login' => :new
  post 'login' => :create
  delete 'logout' => :destroy
end


resources :users

resources :line_items

resources :carts

get "store/index"

resources :products do
  get :who_bought, on: :member
end

resources :line_items do
  put 'decrease', on: :member
  put 'increase', on: :member
end

root to: 'store#index', as: 'store'
```

The problem is now that I'm getting the error:

The @orders variable appears to be empty. Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate?

whenever I click on a "Show" link in the list of orders in the view. Tried restarting the server just in case, but can't get it working :S!

Comment: You should use `link_to 'Show', order_path(order)` and be sure `resources :orders` is present in your routes.

Comment: I've tried that - and order_path(order.id), and resources :orders is already in the routes - I've moved it to the top just to make sure it's the first one picked up, but I'm still getting the same error :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

`<% @orders.each do |order| %>`

not

`<% @customer.orders.each do |order| %>`

Comment: I can't do that - the code is in the customer's show view, and the tables are set up so the customer has_many orders. I'm getting this error when I try what you said: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: title: SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders"  WHERE "orders"."customer_id" = 2 ORDER BY title LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5

Comment: Your code can be in any view, that's not the problem. The error comes from your `order: 'title'`. Are you sure there is a column `title` in the Order model?

Comment: Thank you - you have solved a massive headache! I was being silly and trying to reference it against the name of the product which is stored in a separate table. Thanks again!

Comment: Now I am getting this error when I try and click on the 'Show' link to get to the order itself: The @orders variable appears to be empty. Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate? - no idea why I'm getting that?

Comment: If you see your orders in the paginated pages, it means @orders is not empty. I don't know what your problem might be with Show, but I don't think it has something to do with pagination. Try removing pagination and test it.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check this code

```
@customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
@orders = @customer.orders.paginate page: params[:page], order: 'title',per_page: 5
```

in view

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
```

Comment: That works great for the pagination, thanks, but when I try clicking the 'Show' links to go to the order, I'm getting the following error, any idea why?: The @orders variable appears to be empty. Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate?